# Can you sue someone for parodying your character?

Tags: united-states, copyright, trademark, civil-law

Can you sue someone for parodying your character? Or is this part of free speech? One thing I am always wondering is why people won't use "Google" in movies, especially cartoons, but parody real people like Donald Trump. It's like you can't hurt the brand of a company, but you can hurt the brand of a person. What does the law say on this in the United States?

Comment: "why people won't use "Google" in movies, especially cartoons" Can you give an example of this? I can think of numerous cases of "Google" being mentioned, especially as it is a verb.

Comment: Product placement is a thing. Companies *pay* producers to include their products in the movie. If the company isn't willing to pay for their product to be in the movie, why put it there for free? Hence the generic replacements.

Comment: @chepner It's what's known as "Product *dis*placement".  They'll often use a replacement logo in such a way that it's obvious what it's replacing, like those "Pear" brand laptops, as if to say, "See, Apple, your product *could* have been here, but you didn't wanna pay us, so there."

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Definitions

A brand name is not a "character". Neither is a real person, unless that person is being used as a character in a work of fiction. I will answer what I think the question intends.

One can't really **parody** a real person, but one can use a person fictitiously.

I am using  here a **narrow** definition of "parody", that one parodies a work by imitating it so as to comment on it, often but not always negatively. I exclude from "parody": cases where the events of a work are imitated to tell a different story, or the same story in a different setting -- that is "retelling". (*West Side Story* is a retelling of *Romeo and Juliet*, not a parody, in this sense.) I also exclude cases where the form or style of a work is imitated to make a different point, or for general humorous effect.  That would be satire but not parody.

I am using this narrow sense of parody because it is my understanding that only parody in the narrow sense has been held to be fair use. Satire or retelling is not generally fair use under US law, at least not because of the satire or retelling.

### Copyright

The US Supreme Court has held in [*Campbell v. Acuff-Rose Music, Inc.*, 510 U.S. 569 (1994)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Campbell_v._Acuff-Rose_Music,_Inc.) that a commercial parody can be a fair use. The US Eleventh Circuit court extended this holding to novels in  [*Suntrust Bank v. Houghton Mifflin Co.*, 268 F.3d 1257 (11th Cir. 2001)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suntrust_Bank_v._Houghton_Mifflin_Co.), in which it held that  Alice Randall's 2001 parody, *The Wind Done Gone*, was not an infringement of *Gone with the Wind*

But it is important to note that the definition of "parody" used in those cases is significantly more limited than the use sometimes made of the term in artistic circles or by average people.

The courts held that a parody was fair use specifically because it **commented on the original**. A reworking of a story which did **not** particularly comment on the original, such as *West Side Story* based on *Romeo and Juliet*  would not be fair use, at least not because it was a reworking/parody. (Of course Shakespeare is not protected by modern copyright, but if it were, *West Side Story* might be an infringement.)

The use of the name or description of a real person in a work of fiction would not be an infringement of copyright, as no copyright covers a real person.

### Trademark

Use of a variant of a protected trademark in such a way that reasonable consumers might be confused into thinking that it was created, approved, endorsed or sponsored by the trademark holder would normally be a trademark infringement.

On the other hand a trademark may be used to talk about a product, using the trademark as the **name** of the product. This is known as ***nominative use***.

Thus a character in a book or movie could say "I bought a Ford" or "I looked it up on Google" and it would not be trademark infringement, usually. However, authors and particularly movie-makers do not want to risk a possibly expensive trademark suit and so they often invent product names to avoid any possible risk of trademark infringement claims. The names of people are less often protected than trademarks, although some are.

Some fictional characters have their names or images protected as trademarks, but most do not. Use of the name of a real person could not be trademark infringement, unless that person's name was a protected trademark (rare but it sometimes happens). Even then, use would probably be nominative use unless the public would be likely to be confused into thinking that the person had approved or endorsed the work.

### Defamation

If a person is used as a character in a work of fiction, and the character is portrayed in a negative way, this might give rise to a claim for defamation.

For that claim to hold up, reasonable people would have to think that the description in the work of fiction also applies to the actual person. The work would have to make false factual statements about the person, that harmed the person's reputation.

If the suit were in the US, and the person defamed was a public official or a public figure, the plaintiff would have to prove ***actual malice***. That means proof that statements of fact were made **knowing** that they were false, or with reckless indifference to the truth. Proof of actual malice is often hard to obtain.

Note that a work of fiction can be defamatory if a person is readily recognized, even if the name and some details were changed. For example the movie [*Citizen Kane*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citizen_Kane#Hearst%27s_response) was clearly based on the life of William Randolph Hearst, and Hearst is said to have considered a defamation action.

Comment: Shorter: parody and satire are almost completely privileged from infringement liability. The risk with a real person's name is right of publicity (in addition to defamation).

Comment: Also movie makers would presumably rather ask Google or Ford for money to promote their product, which they can't do if they'd promote it for free anyway.

Comment: @ohwilleke  My understanding is that satire, as opposed to parody, is generally not privileged. I recall a SCOTUS case to that effect, but cannot recall the citation. A mention of right of publicity would add to the answer, but I think it would rarely apply.

Comment: RE: "*One can't really parody a real person...*"  IANAL, but this seems like an overly strong statement given that the history of public comedy is rife with counterexamples: comedians parodying and satirizing public figures, especially politicians.  For example Chevy Chase's multi-year portrayal of Gerald Ford prat-falling is pretty clearly parody.  I doubt the Ford would have had much luck trying to make a defamation case.  And despite how we may talk about them, public figures are real people.

Comment: @DavidSiegel That seems very surprising to me, wouldn't satirizing politicians be a much clearer example of protected speech?  It seems obvious that it is political speech and it has been the basis of cartoons as editorials for well over a hundred years.

Comment: A work satirizing a politician might be protected b ecause that satire would be a comment on the politician and thus on his original speech. But a satire that closely parallel's a prior work, not to comment on that work, but to make a different point, will as I understand it, not be fair use. Consider *Blue Alice* which used the plot of *Alice in Wonderland* to tell a series or erotic episodes. Had they original still been in copyright, I think it would have been an infringement.

Comment: @RBarryYoung "parody" is defined as mimicing the style of a creative work to comment on it. A real person is not a work of art, so you can't parody them. Chase's performance, or a program like "Our Cartoon President", would be classified as satire, not parody. But it's a fine distinction.

Comment: @Barmar Do you mean that's how they would be defined legally?  Because I am fairly certain that that is not how the distinction is made in comedic terminology.

Comment: @RBarryYoung It's also the definition in an ordinary dictionary. https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/parody

Comment: vs. https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/satire

Comment: @Barmar Words have more than one definition.  Citing one of them does not discredit nor disprove any of the others.  For instance [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parody) clearly says that "*But a parody can also be about a real-life person (e.g. a politician), event, or movement*".  Thus in *comedic* terminology (and common use) parodying real people is a real thing and a correct use of the word.  I understand that in legal terminology the distinction might be drawn differently, thus my query above.

Comment: @RBarryYoung OK, it does seem that some conflate parody and satire. But apparently the David Siegel was using the narrower definition in his second paragraph. Whether this is based on a legal issue or simply his personal use of language I can't say. But that doesn't make it wrong, since this is a valid distinction. He could have said, "You can't really parody a person, but you can satirize them."

Comment: @Bamar OK, I see what DavidSiegel was saying now.  However, comedic jargon does make a distinction between parody and satire, it just doesn't have anything to do with whether the subject is a literary work or not but rather whether the material presented has a point beyond just humor.

Comment: @Barmar I was indeed using a narrow definition of parody, because my understanding is that is how the term has been used in copyright cases, particularly in fair use analysis. I am not attempting to make a literary point here, that would be for literature.SE or ELU.SE. I have edited the answer to make this clear.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Please see my comment to Barmar just above.

Comment: @RBarryYoung The distinction is if your work required the previous work or not. If you make fun of a song by rewriting the lyrics to the same music, your work is reliant on the previous work, so it is justified (per US Supreme Court). If you make fun of a politician by writing new lyrics over existing music, your work didn't require the previous work (song), and it is not justified to use the song. You can be protected from the politician because it's political commentary but still open to being sued by the copyright holder for copyright infringement.

Comment: There is Paolo Roberto, a Swedish ex-boxer, who was the inspiration for a boxing trainer of the same name in the book “The girl who played with fire” and actually played the part of that boxing trainer in the movie. However, apart from the name they seem to be different people.

Comment: @gnasher729 Certainly fictional characters are often more or less based on real people. But I would not call that a "parody". Sherlock Holmes was based in part on Joseph Bell, O'Brian's Jack Aubry on Lord Cochrane. But those are not parodies.. Now Harry Harrison's Capt. Honorio Harplayer is an obvious parody of Horatio Hornblower, and might have been considered an infringement as a derivative work, although Forrester did not complain or sue.